# Fazer histograma em Python

Tags: python

Olá!
Estou fazendo um histograma em Python, mas na linha histogram = Counter(decile(grades) for grade in grades) encontro erro com a função Counter.
Já fiz o teste utilizando o import collections mas não consegui.
A seguir as linhas até aqui desenvolvidas:

```
grades = [83, 95 ,91, 87, 70, 0, 85, 82, 100, 67, 73, 77, 0]
decile = lambda grade: grade / 10 * 10
histogram = collections.Counter(decile(grades) for grade in grades)
```

Answer (score 0):

Mauro, o import realmente é necessário.

O erro está no for dentro do Counter, você enviou a lista e não o item da mesma:

```
import collections

grades = [83, 95 ,91, 87, 70, 0, 85, 82, 100, 67, 73, 77, 0]
decile = lambda grade: grade / 10 * 10
histogram = collections.Counter(decile(grade) for grade in grades)
```

Comment: Obrigado Daniel! Neste caso, qual seria estrutura adequada?

Answer (score -3):

Coloque...

```
from collections import Counter
```

Comment: Como ele usou `collections.Counter`, o correto seria apenas `import collections`. Ou faltou complementar sua resposta colocando como seria ao fazer o `import` como sugerido.